Docker-compose configuration to run multiple chains on Safe infrastructure
The documentation says we have to run one instances each of Safe-transaction service for each chain, but the docker-compose file doesn't have txs-db under the Safe-Transaction-service and has txs-db under common nginx and database, and it says in the readme we should have a Postgres instance for each chain. My questions are

Do we need a separate instance of this txs-db too?
In the env file txn.env

EVENTS_QUEUE_URL=amqp://general-rabbitmq:5672

So do I also need a separate amqp and celery instances, since there's no mention of multiple events service instance


Yes, you will need a separate instance of txs-db for each chain you support;
Yes, you will also need a separate amqp and celery instances for each chain.

Hope it helps; Best, Louis
